# Android Studio , BT socket null point error ,

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

[Click here to download codes for the app working](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0AT63YryKWCWGZuc1psMlVNTWs)

I am using the color picker app which works individually very well , i updated it with bt connectivity to HC_05 device and still working good, later i tried to create the new_activity and tried to send data to HC--05 do not work ,

after reading several hours to google and stackoverflow , i could not manage to do much

Really appreciate if someone can help to put the codes together , i will owe one cheers and many thanks

code is attached

Answer (score 1):

Vinay. I'm working on a similar android- arduino project - smart LED controller. There is very good example from Google on how to use Bluetooth connectivity - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat . I've been following this example to get things going. There is my project - https://github.com/AlexShutov/LEDLights . Feel free to use code from there. Notice, that you have to connect to HC-05 from you phone (not accept connection from HC-05).

Comment: Thank you Alex , I read the Chat  code , Ya i am using one way connections because particularly for this one i don't need any return communication from Arduini or HC , Just i am trying to get a new activity that will allow me to give predefined colors to My LED controller .